# NullpointerException using findElements in Selenium and alter is not handled

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

1. Getting NullPointerException when I use findElements method with list. Tried with POM model as well getting the same error. commented the findelements portion of the code and tested it works fine. I am not sure what is wrong in my code.
2. Location alert is not handled by the alert defined in the code getting no alter found exception .

What need to be fixed in my code?

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

class CleartripPOM1 {
    WebDriver driver;
    private String url="https://www.cleartrip.com/";
    public CleartripPOM1(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
}

By from=By.xpath("//input[@title='Any worldwide city or airport' and @etitle='From']");
By to=By.xpath("//input[@title='Any worldwide city or airport' and @etitle='To']");
By date=By.xpath("//input[@id='DepartDate']");
By adults=By.id("Adults");
By childerns=By.cssSelector("select[name='childs'][id='Childrens']" );
By infants=By.name("infants");
By search=By.xpath("//input[@id='SearchBtn']");
By airline=By.xpath("//li[@class='vendor']/a");
By depart=By.xpath("//li[@class='depart']/a");
By duration=By.xpath("//li[@class='duration']/a");
By price=By.xpath("//li[@class='price']/a");
private List <WebElement>coupon =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/td/span"));
private List <WebElement> airName=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th/small"));
private List <WebElement> departure=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='depart']"));
private List <WebElement> arrival=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='arrive']"));
private List <WebElement> travelTime=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='duration']"));
private List <WebElement> ticketFare=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='price']"));

public ArrayList<String> airlineNames(List<WebElement>el) {
    ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement e:el) {
        names.add(e.getText());
    }
    return names;
}

public void url_launch() {
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
//  WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
//  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
//  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
//  alert.dismiss();

}
public void actions(By e, String location) {
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    Action action= act.click(driver.findElement(e)).sendKeys(location).build();
    action.perform();
}

public void selection(By e,String selection) {
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(e));
    select.selectByValue(selection);

}
public void searchFlights() {
    actions(from,"Chennai");
    actions(to,"Madurai");
    actions(date,"25/08/2018");
    driver.findElement(date).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    selection(adults,"2");
    selection(childerns,"3");
    selection(infants,"1");
    driver.findElement(search).click();
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='vendor']/a")));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(coupon));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(airName));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(departure));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(arrival));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(travelTime));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(ticketFare));
```

**Runner code:**

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CleartripPOM1 ct= new CleartripPOM1(driver);
        ct.url_launch();
        ct.searchFlights();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1:**
You are initializing all the instance Web Element before initailzing the `driver` variable and hence it is throwing `NullPointerException`. Instance Web Element  initialization needs to be moved inside the constructor else needs to be moved in side the method where that particular element is required.

I have given two approach with sample of two elements. Please change all the instance element initialization with any one of the below approach.

For Example:

**Approach 1 :** Initialize the instance webelement in the constructor.So, that all the WebElement can be accessed in all the methods within a class.

```
    WebDriver driver;

    private List <WebElement>coupon;
    private List <WebElement> airName;
    private String url="https://www.cleartrip.com/";
    public CleartripPOM1(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        coupon=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/td/span"));
        airName=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th/small"));
        -----------
        ----------- and so on

    }
```

**Approach 2:** Initialize the instance WebElement only inside a method where is required. Suppose you want to access coupon and airname element list only in certain method , then you can initialize in that particular method alone

```
    WebDriver driver;

    private List <WebElement>coupon;
    private List <WebElement> airName;
    private String url="https://www.cleartrip.com/";
    public CleartripPOM1(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;

    }

    public void travelDetails(){
        coupon=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/td/span"));
        airName=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th/small"));
         -----------
         ----------- and so on

   }
```

**#2**  Regarding Alert, you are getting the chrome specific notification.So, you need to disable notification option as below in the driver initialization part

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Edit :

**To solve the follow up Question:**

After Performing the search action only, you are getting the result section and all the List WebElement is identified from the result section.So, you need to initialize all the List WebElement after performing the search action as below.

Regarding the Web Element declaration, If you want to access the same WebElement in different method as well, then you can declare the WebElement as instance.If the List WebElement scope only in searchFlights method, then I would suggest to declare inside the searchFlights method instead of instance declaration.

Search Method needs to be changed :

```
public void searchFlights() {
    actions(from,"Chennai");
    actions(to,"Madurai");
    actions(date,"25/08/2018");
    driver.findElement(date).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    selection(adults,"2");
    selection(childerns,"3");
    selection(infants,"1");
    driver.findElement(search).click();
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='vendor']/a")));

    coupon =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/td/span"));
    airName=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th/small"));
    departure=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='depart']"));
    arrival=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='arrive']"));
    travelTime=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='duration']"));
    ticketFare=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='listView flights']/li/table/tbody/tr/th[@class='price']"));


    System.out.println(airlineNames(coupon));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(airName));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(departure));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(arrival));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(travelTime));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(ticketFare));


}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help me why the alert is not handled in this portion of code                                                                                                                                                                                                                         //  WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
//  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
//  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
//  alert.dismiss();

Comment: @Subburajone more issue i facing is i getting empty list for the below function call but it should return the string value for the xpath. I have verified the xpath its correct can you please help here as well  
        System.out.println(airlineNames(coupon));
 System.out.println(airlineNames(airName));
 System.out.println(airlineNames(departure));
 System.out.println(airlineNames(arrival));
 System.out.println(airlineNames(travelTime));
 System.out.println(airlineNames(ticketFare));

Comment: After Performing the search action only, you are getting the result.So, you need to initialize all the List WebElement in between this two lines     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='vendor']/a")));
    System.out.println(airlineNames(coupon));.  I have updated the answer for the second Question as well. Please check the updated answer

Comment: I have edited the answer with the above issue as well.Please check the updated answer. If you are satisfied with the above answer, please don't forget to give the up vote and consider accepting the answer.